# Different Orientation for each line in Jtextpane

Tags: java, text, jtextpane

I want to append text in JTextPane , i make every line have different color, but when i tried to make line from left to right and right to left it's not workding

this is my code for method

```
private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c , String rientation)
{
        ComponentOrientation ornt = ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT;

        if(orientation.equals("left"))
            ornt = ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT;


        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

        AttributeSet or     =  sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Orientation , StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT );
        AttributeSet fnt    = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Background , Color.YELLOW);
        AttributeSet fontSize = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.FontSize, 25);

         // aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
         // aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

        int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
        tp.setCaretPosition(len);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(or , false);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(fnt, false);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(fontSize, false);


//      if(orientation.equals("left"))
//          tp.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
//      else
//          tp.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

//      if(orientation != null)
//          tp.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
//      else
//          tp.setAlignmentX(orientation);

//      tp.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        tp.replaceSelection(msg);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to alternate orientation or alignment? I can't imagine a case where switching orientation would be a good idea...

Comment: Hey  @Sharcoux thanks for replay , yes i want change orientation for one line in jtextpane if you know how to use this method right
i tried this 
AttributeSet or     =  sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Orientation , StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT );

and this too

AttributeSet or     =  sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Orientation , ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT );

both is not work for me

Comment: Ok, i will help you as soon as I get back my computer (it's hard to show code from a phone). In the meantime,  check methods from StyledDocument that you can access from tp.getDocument() to set the attributes. You might have to create your own view to achieve what you want, but I will let you know in this case.

Comment: Thanks bro, take my e-mail : ahmedadmnagem@gmail.com , my i contact with you for business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if your goal is to change the alignment, here is your code sample:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");

                JTextPane testPane = new JTextPane();
                testPane.setText("left\nright");

                StyledDocument doc = testPane.getStyledDocument();

                //left alignment
                SimpleAttributeSet myAttributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                StyleConstants.setAlignment(myAttributeSet, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);
                doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 4, myAttributeSet, false);

                //right alignment
                StyleConstants.setAlignment(myAttributeSet, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                doc.setParagraphAttributes(5, 9, myAttributeSet, false);

                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.getContentPane().add(testPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(200,200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If your goal is to change orientation of the text, check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/examples/BidiTextComponentDemo.java) about [Bidirectional text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/bidi.html).

If your goal is to just write text from right to left, you can just add a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to your document and reverse the logic of your document from there (backward will become forward, the caret will be moved before the insertion instead of after, inserted text will be mirrored, etc)

If you could show more clearly what is your expected result, we would probably be of more help to you.